# Difference between prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Let $p_n$ denote the $n$th prime number and $\phi:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ an increasing function, with $\phi(n)>n$.

Is it true that $p_{\phi(n+1)}-p_{\phi(n)}<p_{\phi(n)}$ for infinitely many $n$ ?

Is it true that $p_{\phi(n+1)}-p_{\phi(n)}> p_{\phi(n)}$ for infinitely many $n$ ?

Comment: The question does not actually deal with prime-gaps. They only occur between consecutive primes.

Comment: It will depend on $\phi$.  Consider $\phi(n)=n$ and $\phi(n)=2^n$